# Why is there an electric mono-charge?

Tags: electrostatics, charge

I am in advanced UG (in Elec Engg). I was consolidating a mental model to help in (most of) engineering applications.
I read Griffith recently.

I learned that there exists no magnetic charge, (although, as Griffith said - how cute the scenario would have been, if they did.)

Intuitively so; as Magnetic fields are engendered by time-variance of electric phenomenon (in field or charge (as current)), I never expected their existence.

But, why the world needs a concept that is "charge"?

- The Gauss law, firmly relates the charge concept to the field. Intuitively, the field fluxes out of charge. It may seem that charge is engendering the field. But, let's believe in absence of such concept; the field is inexplicably (concentrated) sourced at "some" places - say **S**.
- Here is an argument - It is ambiguous whether the charge carries the energy or field. In the absence of charge concept; the field carries the energy; then the source to this energy are **S**.
- Energy is a transient phenomenon; Charge concept could represent the source to these new perturbations in the field.

Coming to the title of the question.
There is no magnetic monopole.
Why is there an electric mono-charge?
Clearly, charge represents transfer of energy from other domain of energy into electrical domain. Transfer of energy is relative.
Can't we say the other half of the charge exists in the other domain of energy? (imaginary pole).

I have an argument to address the polar nature of charge as well.
But, I have already revulsed enough physicists here.
(Excuse me, I was just thinking.)

Comment: "Clearly, charge represents transfer of energy from other domain of energy into electrical domain." - No, I don't see that clearly. A lone electron in space has a charge (as does a long proton).

Comment: I understand the argument that "charge is the property of matter". Given a open system as Universe, what do you think is causing differential changes in charge $\frac{dq}{dt}$? If "energy is conserved", beyond this, it is either transferable or transformable.

Comment: Do you think the total amount of charge in the universe is changing? Why?

Comment: "Net charge is conserved", I believe. But still there is a flow energy. There is electrical energy. 
I meant the meaning of charge; I explained above I meant it synonymous with energy. 
It could be that this flow of energy break charge evenly? thats how net is conserved. Is there actual no mono charge? Is it hypothetical setup for electrostatic study? Like the point charge?

Comment: What is happening is that you are confusing the distinct and different concepts of charge and energy into one mess. You cannot convert them into each other because, for example, neutral objects exist and can have energy. There is no energetic method from which you can change the total amount of charge in a system. Whatever you call S in the question _is_ charge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But, why the world needs a concept that is "charge"?

It doesn’t really matter if it is needed or not. The fact that electromagnetism *can* be formulated in terms of charge means that at some point it would be. If we consider alternative representations, they are all mathematically equivalent to charges.

If we had started with a field formulation then we would have noticed that the field is divergence-free in vacuum, but it can have positive, negative, or no divergence in matter. So we could then characterize matter by its E field divergence, which is charge.

If we had started with a potential formulation then as soon as Noether proved her amazing theorem we would have been able to look at the gauge symmetry of the potentials and obtain charge as the corresponding conserved quantity.

You had mentioned energy, but I am skeptical that could be done without discovering charge anyway. After all, the potential energy of a charge requires the concept of a charge. However, if such a formulation were produced then it would still have a potential, and again charge would be discovered through Noether’s theorem. Since the gauge symmetry is a separate symmetry from the time symmetry it implies a separate conserved quantity, so once Noether’s theorem was developed charge was inevitable.

Regardless, the concept of charge would be discovered and because conserved quantities are useful, it would be used.

Comment: I see, in physics, we have things because of the virtue of them being there. (Like in math we deduce theorems because for the sake of it and because it could be done.)
However, conception of charge felt like a redundancy. I will seldom be dealing with them. Thanks!
Some comments-
Would it be flawed to say - "Electric field (Aether) is the property of universe" because "Charge is the property of matter" and "Net charge is conserved".  
`field is divergence-free in vacuum`
Of course, in the hypothetical electrostatic setup; are there charges without fields?

Comment: @KartikPandey yes, that would be flawed. The aether is not the electric field. For one, the electric field is useful and the aether is not. The aether didn’t die because you could not formulate electromagnetism in terms of it. It died because it is not useful to do so. No, there are no charges without fields.

Comment: @KartikPandey *charge … I will seldom be dealing with them.* It seems odd to me that an electrical engineer would say this since electricity is the flow of charges.

Comment: @Ghoster I mean, I can think of EM in perspective of currents and fields. I will think of charges as "very slow currents" (is that quasi-static?); the point is I don't want to consider the static (or charges) case at all. A mental model would help think faster even if its wrong generally.

Comment: @KartikPandey Trying to think about electrostatics in terms of currents seems very strange to me, and I cannot understand why you want to consider current to be more fundamental than charge.

Comment: @KartikPandey said “I can think of EM in perspective of currents and fields”. I am skeptical that is true. I know of Maxwell’s equations in terms of fields, charges, and currents. There are also charges in both the quasi electrostatic and quasi magnetostatic approximations. I know of circuit theory in terms of currents and voltages without charges. And I know of geometric optics in terms of rays without charges. But I don’t know of any formulation in terms of currents and fields without charges. It is not trivial to develop valid adaptations, and it cannot be done simply by wishing it were so

Comment: @Dale Thanks for the concerning comment. To think, I meant to develop a mental model for a particular scenario. Thus, to act quicker at the cost of not being book accurate. (That's what I do for all my subjects, even for math). I want a time evolving visualization in my head. And I just could not digest static nature of the subject with dynamic one.
Of course, I am not being astute here; neither do I wish to. 
I can develop different mental models of different applications of the same subject. (might just click with the correct one later; I just a UG).

Comment: @Ghoster Even the point of this post was to clarify if I could see charges as the spots where energy is transfered to an electrical system. That would be too much flawed, I believe. (Not completely wrong though).